# Get image folder URI from controller and twig template

Tags: php, symfony, uri, symfony-2.3

I moved all the public images of my website to a folder out of the web folder of symfony so it can be shared with other web applications.
I created a symbolic link to this folder so it can be accessed from the web folder of the symfony application.

```
ln -s /absolute/path/to/images /path/to/symfony/application_01/web/images
ln -s /absolute/path/to/images /path/to/symfony/application_02/web/images
```

Etc... for all applications.

I'm looking for a method that would allow me to retrieve the images URI in my development environment on localhost **as well as** in my production environment on the remote web server.

I would like to be able to retrieve this URI from the twig template **AND** from the controller.

Basically (for my application_01 for instance):

In the **development environment** it would return:

```
http://localhost/images/my_image.jpg
```

In the **production environment**, it would return:

```
http://www.application_01.com/images/my_image.jpg
```

My problem is that I found lots of different ways to get URIs but I'm not totally clear about how Symfony manages them and what functions to use to have a global solution working in all cases.

What is the best way to achieve my goal?

---

**EDIT**

Specifically I found some SO answers to quite similar questions proposing to use the following functions:

$request->getScheme();
$request->getHttpHost();

That seems to correspond to the values or superglobals $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] and $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']

And I don't know if this is the proper way to get this information since this is linked to the current request received by the server.

Isn't there another way to get this info independently from the request currently processed by the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the following url

image_url:
    path: /images/{image}

Then use it like this

```
/** @var Router $router */
$router = $this->get('router');
$url = $router->generate('image_url', ['image' => 'my_image.jpg'], Router::ABSOLUTE_URL);
```

$url now contains the absolute url to your image. And of course it's the best practice you can think of :)

----- Answer to your comment about app_dev.php
We used this solution in our company months ago.

```
    preg_replace('#/(.+?)\.php)', '', $router->generate('my_url');
```

http://techimho.com/index.php/2015/10/15/generate-production-url-in-dev-environment/

Comment: Perfect, this works. I just tested it. Just needed a minute to understand the second line. This is actually a definition to put in the routing config file. Thanks for your help. It was not that difficult but I couldn't put my finger on this solution by myself.

Comment: I'm not allowed to post another question because this one is too recent but I have an issue. Since the image path contains subfolders deduced from the image name itself (a12f23.jpg is stored in /01/2f/ subfolder) Symfony doesn't accept my 'image' parameter. It doesn't accept special '/' characters in the image name (/01/2f/012f23.jpg). Any clue how to make Symfony accept this kind of picture name embedding subfolders?

Comment: @Nitseg http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html
Google is your friend ;)

Comment: Yes, but it was time to go to lunch. Sorry, bad excuse... ;-)

Comment: Finally it doesn't really solve the issue since app_dev.php (in dev environment) is put in between  the address and hence the client tries to access the image from: http://localhost/app_dev.php/images/my_image.jpg instead of http://localhost/images/my_image.jpg.
Looking further into the symfony code I figured out the $router->generate() function uses $this->context->getHttpHost() and getHttpScheme().
I'm afraid I cannot use $router->generate() straight...

Comment: Well, I went for getHttpHost() and getHttpScheme() solution but your solution with regexp also works. I don't know which one of both is cleaner and I'm still looking for a cleaner and smarter solution (no offense) if existing. Will approve your solution in a couple of days if no other better solution. Thanks.